# How to get data from windows form

Tags: c++, windows, forms

i wanted to get the value of a TextBox in a form and use it in main.cpp. How would i do this? Sorry if this is unclear i have never used forms. i am using windows 7, VC++ 2010.

Comment: do you know anything about window handles, messages etc?

Comment: The programming model for a GUI app is drastically different from what you are used to.  You don't stick code in a main.cpp file, for one.  You'd stick it in a method of your form class that you call from, say, an OK button's Click event handler.  Trial and error are not a good way to learn these techniques, get a book or an education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send it a WM_GETTEXT message. If it's your form in your process then you will know the window handle. Otherwise you've got to get hold of it by some means.

Comment: This is my form window. like i call Application::Run(gcnew Form1()); Then i want to find it.

Comment: What? Dude i have no idea how.

Comment: find a book on WinForms and start there. You'll might have to wade through a bit of C#.